# SQL row names and row flags

Tags: sql, flags

I have trouble understanding row flags. The below question can clear it for me:

**Is it possible to store a name and its flag in the same cell in SQL?**

Consider:

If you have a table known as `cars` with the columns `number_plate, colour`, and `brand_name`. The `brand_name` has a `name` and a `flag`.

How would one store that in a single column? If it is not possible or advised, explain why and how to do it.

How would you then get the number of `cars` from a given `country` (based on the unique `number_plate`(primary key)) and the country `flag`?

Comment: Hint:  `JSON`.  In general, though, if you know there are two values, use two columns.

Comment: @GordonLinoff, in that case (splitting `brand_name` and `country_flag`), is brand_name of no importance when I am searching for cars and their country of origin? Moreover, how would I insert into the `country_flag` column or perform select operations based on the `country_flag`? Information on row flags is quite limited on the web.

Comment: What is a flag? Do you mean the symbol associated with geographic entities (you also use "country_flag"), or do you mean "bit wise value (true/false)". What is the relationship between "brandname" and "flag"?

Comment: @NevilleKuyt,  I mean `bitwise value (true/false)`. For now, let us just put a simple relationship like Mercedes is German, Chevrolet is American, Toyota is Japanese. I suspect this is a silly example. I could not come up with a better relationship that warrants the use of a flag.

Comment: @NevilleKuyt my explanation above does not appear to be  `bit wise value (true/false)`.  Let's say Mercedes, and Chevrolet are classified as `West` and Toyota as `East`

Comment: Skip the flag, add country column instead. (Or, if you want to be able to store several countries for a brand, create a separate car_country table, where you for each brand have one row per country.)

Answer (score 0):

I *think* you are trying to design a schema but haven't quite got the hang of foreign keys.

In your example, you'd have the following tables:

```
country:
country_id     name      continent
-----------------------------------
1             Germany      Europe
2             Japan         Asia
3            USA         N.America


Brand
Brand_id      name      country_id (foreign key)
---------------------------------------------
1            Mercedes                      1
2            Toyota                        2
3              BMW                         1
4            Chrysler                      3


Car
Number_plate    colour         brand_id
------------------------------------------
xxx-yy-zz         Green               1
aa-bb-cc            Red               1
kkk-l-mmm         Orange              2
....
```

To find the number of cars, based on the country where the brand is based, you'd do something like:

```
select country.name, 
            count(*)
from car
inner join brand on car.brand_id = brand.brand_id
inner join country on brand.country_id = country.country_id
group by country.name
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's say `name` and `flag` are two separate columns. Using `concat` function they can be stored into a single column named `brand_name`.

```
select number_plate, colour, concat(name,' ',flag) as brand_name from cars
```

To get the count of `cars`(unique) based on a flag

```
select * from 
(select 
 distinct number_plate, 
 colour, 
 concat(name,' ',flag) as brand_name from cars
) a 
where brand_name like '%UK%'
```

[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=93b416c14d484df91919d0637b89e7ef)